# Combinatorial Proof of a simple identity involvig Binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics

I need to prove the identity $$\binom{a}{b} =  \binom{a}{a - b}, \text{ with } 0 \leq b \leq a.$$

Proving this using its definition, $$\binom{a}{b} = \frac{a!}{b! \left( a - b \right)!}, \text{ with } 0 \leq b \leq a,$$ is straightforward. But I need to give a combinatorial proof using the fact that the binomial coefficient $\binom{a}{b}$ is the number of $b$-subsets of a set with $a$ elements.

Please provide some hints to solve this problem (not the full solution since I am supposed to do it myself).

Comment: When choosing two elements from a set of ten, you are also choosing eight elements by virtue of not choosing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: when you choose a set with $b$ elements, how many elements does its complement have?

Comment: Of course, every $b$-subset defines a $(a - b)$-subset which is its complement, and this sets are unique. Hence there the number of $b$-subset and $(a - b)$-subsets is  the same.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Felipe no problem.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: For a set $E$, prove that a bijection exists between $F_b$,  (which got $a \choose b$ elements) and $F_{a-b}$ (which got $a \choose a-b$ elements).

Think to the complement of a set that got $b$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

say you have a set $S$ with $n=a+b$ elements and $A$ is a subset having $a$ elements.

consider the action of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $A$. the elements of $S_n$ which leave $A$ invariant belong to the subgroup $S_a \times S_b$, where $S_a$ permutes only elements of $A$ and $S_b$ permutes only the elements of the complement of $A$. since:

$$
|S_a \times S_b|= a! b!
$$
the number of subsets in the orbit of $A$ under $S_n$ is therefore:
$$
\frac{|S_n|}{|S_a \times S_b|}=\frac{n!}{a!b!}
$$
and these are exactly the subsets of $S$ which have the same cardinality as $A$. the symmetry of the construction shows that the orbit of the complement of $A$ has the same cardinality